# Convert Intrinsic xmm register into uint8_t array[16]

Tags: c, type-conversion, intrinsics

How can I efficiently dump xmm register into uint8_t array[16]?

Comment: (I have no idea, but I believe you should specify what compiler you're using, and what CPU.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[_mm_store_si128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edk11s13%28VS.80%29.aspx) stores the sse2 register contents to the memory specified.
_mm_store_ps and _mm_store_pd are the variants used for float or double register contents. When the destination is unaligned, you must use storeu.

```
__m128i var;
__declspec( align(16) ) uint8_t array[16];

_mm_store_si128( (__m128i*) array, var );
```

Comment: But its microsoft specific...., I am using linux on intel hardware, and I need to convert and ipv6 address (uint8_t addr[16]) to an __m128 entity.. any ideas ?

Comment: You want to use [_mm_loadu_si128](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f4k12ae8(v=vs.90).aspx) for loading unaligned data into an SSE register. The __declspec( align( 16 ) ) can be replaced by the equivalent gcc/clang/etc property ... alignas (?)

Answer (score 3):

how about `memcpy()`? Doc [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/).

```
__m128d var;
uint8_t array[16];

memcpy(array, &var, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: `array` instead of `&array[0]` should be prettier.